# How to extract from a Python list while also accounting for the position of the extracted elements?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, indexing

Given a `list` **x** e.g.

```
[4,6,7,21,1,7,3]
```

I need to extract those values that are `less than or equal to 4`. This is easily done, but I also need to take some note of *where in the list* those values occurred. If all values were unique I know I could probably use `list.index()` in some way. But there will be duplicated values. How best to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe a loop using `enumerate(x)`, which returns tuples `(i, v)`, where `i` is an index and `v` is the list value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about simply

```
[(i, val) for i, val in enumerate([[4,6,7,21,1,7,3]) if val <= 4]
```

or depending on your use-case, perhaps a dictionary would be more suitable? Either from index to value:

```
{i:val for i, val in enumerate([4,6,7,21,1,7,3]) if val <= 4}
```

or from value to index:

```
from collections import defaultdict

indexes = defaultdict(list)
for i, val in enumerate([4,6,7,21,1,7,3]):
    if val <= 4:
        indexes[val].append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make another list which will store tuples of the elements less than equal to 4 as first element and their index as second element, like this:

```
    my_list = [4, 6, 7, 21, 1, 7, 3]
    req_list = []
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        e = my_list[i]
        if e <= 4:
            req_list.append((e, i))
```

here req_list will have pair-tuples with the first element as the element less than equal to 4 and the second element the index of that element.
e.g.

if

my_list = [4, 6, 7, 21, 1, 7, 3]

then

req_list = [(4, 0), (1, 4), (3, 6)]